# How can I bind and unbind unique event listeners to the same object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following javascript:

```
$.each(idArray, function (index, value) {
    $('#'+value).on('mouseenter', function(event) {
        showTooltip();
        $(document).on('click', function (event) {
            if(!$(event.target).is('#'+value)) {
                hideTooltip();
                //remove this listener
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I remove each 'click' listener once it's fired, and Is there any way to uniquely identify them and remove them from somewhere else? Obviously I can't unbind 'click' on the document element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [event.namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) for it.

```
$.each(idArray, function (index, value) {
    $('#' + value).on('mouseenter', function (event) {
        showTooltip();
        $(document).on('click.tooltip', function (event) {
            if (!$(event.target).is('#' + value)) {
                hideTooltip();
                //remove this listener
                $(this).off('click.tooltip');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', function handlerName(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is('#'+value)) {
        hideTooltip();
        $(this).off('click', handlerName);
    }
});
```

Here you're assigning a name to an anonymous function and then using it to detach the handler.